Are there any responsa on a shul changing davening time on Xmas morning
The morning davening time usually is later on federal holidays, and Xmas is a federal holiday.
But making an adjustment for Xmas has a funny feel to it.
Are there responsa on this topic?

What's the problem? If people have time off from work why can't they have a lie in with their shul having a later minyan?

@Dov The problem is benefiting from Xmas (sleeping later) or simply acknowledging Xmas as a salient day.

In my Shul we deliberately exclude 12/25 from the usual Federal Holiday time changes, except we skip the late Maariv simply due to lack of demand. But at least one other Shul in the neighborhood is having a different schedule (listed as "Erev Chanukah and Federal Holiday").

@YehudaW I don't think you are acknowledging the day by going to shul later? You have a day off due to a national holiday. What do I care - I don't celebrate it?

@Dov A church is a federally recognized 501c3 but I still can't acknowledge it in e.g. giving directions. Just because something has a legal status doesn't negate its fundamental character.

Couldn't you make a similar argument about Sundays?

@shmosel Maybe when they first became a day off, because the initial reason was religious; but now, they’re just part of the weekend. This is different from Christmas, which is still inherently Christio-pagan; The Sunday day-off has completely lost any semblance of its original purpose.

Rav Yehuda Herzl Henkin z"l discussed this in Benei Vanim 3:37. The responsum is mostly about Thanksgiving. He says that a later minyan time is permitted on Thanksgiving and even on Christmas since everyone knows it's because people are off from work. However, he says it's worthwhile to not have a later time on Christmas so as to emphasize that we do not participate in Christmas.

For places that are davening uneasily early this time of year vis-a-vis sunrise, they are between a rock and a hard place -- continue davening just-barely-late-enough, or change things up in some way and thereby somehow acknowledging that 12/25 is not a normal day.

@Shalom I don't think R' Henkin would have opposed davening at Hanetz.

Takke I know of one shul that instead of davening the usual weekday time (uncomfortably early) or the usual time for Sundays and federal holidays, scheduled it davka for hanetz. Still feels a bit funny...

@Shalom ירבו כמותם בישראל
